# AngularJS ui-router- Use filters in ui-sref with parameters?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Suppose if we have to modify or do some prepossessing on parameters of ui-sref like below:

```
ui-sref="post({postId: post.post_id, postTitle: post.post_title | myFilter )})"
```

As shown if I want to apply my custom filter to parameter, is there any way to it?

I have tried like above, but it didn't worked and was giving syntax color.

The other solution could be probably to modify attribute in `controller` only, but that it not feasible for me, as these data is coming from server in list and I don't think to pre-process it in controller is good idea just for this.

Any suggestions this can be achieved?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes you can, however you need to wrap each parameter in parenthesis like so:

```
ui-sref="post({postId: (post.post_id | myFilter), postTitle: (post.post_title | myFilter)})"
```

Example, using lowercase filter:

```
ui-sref="post({postId: (post.post_id | lowercase), postTitle: (post.post_title | lowercase)})"
```